# Break Text With CSS

Tags: php, css, break, words

I am developing a forum software for a site.

Anyway,
With the description say if I added 100 words it will just go across the page and it will not break down
(I want it like this how I moved this to a new line)

I would I make it break down once it gets to the end of the first line or after a certain number of characters.

If it's not possible with CSS how could I do this in PHP then.

Thanks!

Comment: would you try css word-break property ?

Comment: the web browser does this automatically if the length is greater than the elements width

Comment: You do not want to specify a length like this or it's going to look bad, most of the time - (all of those times you haven't run into yet.) You must have something set as `white-space: nowrap` here is a fiddle for you to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/KHzzW/

Answer (score 2):

using CSS:

try limiting the width of the container `div` of the text and add `word-wrap` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
```

Where 20 is the number of characters before the line break.

Comment: what would be the best way to do for a forum software?
Since this is custom made and only currently needs to be designed for me I can use wordwrap and keep adjusting it.

But what would Mybb,PHPBB doing? (the professional way)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this link:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php 
You'll find that this is possible with PHP's string function: wordwrap()

For example:

```
<?php
    $text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
    $newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
    echo $newtext;
?>
```

Will output:

```
The quick brown fox<br />
jumped over the lazy<br />
dog.
```

See link for more examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: I have tried that if the text was inputed like this "ssssssssslslsl" so without spaces it will not break them this is only a minor issue that I can fix over time but would be great if I can find a way to detect how many letters have been inputed.

Thanks for your help so far ;)

And when I get to creating a new topic feature how would I get it to break when the theme detects it might go over the line and run the layout!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is simply about limiting the line length, set a maximum width on the element where the text is contained.  For example, if the text is inside `<p>` element(s), set

```
p {
  max-width: 25em;
  max-width: 60ch;
}
```

This sets the maximum width of any `p` element to about 60 characters. (The `ch` unit is the width of the digit zero, which is close to an average width of characters, typically. The first declaration is backup setting for browsers that do not support `ch`.)

Text will normally wrap at any whitespace character as needed to satisfy the constraint on width.

Comment: also I think the browser does automatically do it once you add a theme or tables :/
Not sure need to test it, It should